# how to show the time using time class and function

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class time
{
    protected:
        int hr;

    public:
        void settime()
        {
            time_t now = time(0);
            tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
            display(1 + ltm->tm_hour);
        }
        void display(int a)
        {
            hr=a;
            cout<<hr;
        }
};
int main( )
{
     time t;
     t.settime();

     return 0;
}
```

The question is like this: 
Provide a constructor that is capable of using the current time from the time() function - declared in the C standard Library header time.h - to initialize an object of the time class. 
I not so understand about the class and is it this way is true. 
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please decipher this: `I not so understand about the class and is it this way is true`

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a proper answer(code) to question. In question clearly ask to create constructor. So no need to define **settime()** function separately. You should create a constructor and place the current time code inside that constructor. I have given a code below. Please be clear with your question dude.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class time
{
    protected:
    int hr;

    public:

    time()
    {

      time_t now = time(0);

      tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

      display(1 + ltm->tm_hour);
}
  void display(int a)
  {
    hr=a;
    cout<<hr;
  }
}
int main( )
{
  time t;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I got this from another answer some where in SO. Try this:

```
time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-' 
     << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
     <<  now->tm_mday
     << endl;
```

Hope it helps.. )

Answer (score 0):

if you want to initialize your class object member with current time. 
Add time_t variable and tm type pointer in your class and constructor to your class

```
class time {
           private :
           time_t now;
           tm *ltm;
           ...
      };
```

In constructor

```
time::time()
{
        now = time(0);
        tm = localtime(&now);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a private representation of type `tm` or `time_t` in the class to store time.
2. You need to init it in the constructor with the current time.
3. Add a method to print the time according to it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Time.h
 * 1.Provide a constructor that is capable of using the current
 time from the time() function declared in the C++
 Standard Library header <ctime> to initialize an object of
 the Time class.
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 8, 2014
 *      Author: miro
 */
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef TIME_H_
#define TIME_H_

class Time {
private:
    time_t now;
    struct tm *ltm;
public:
    void tick();
    void showSec();
    Time();
    virtual ~Time();
    tm*& getLtm() ;
    void setLtm( tm*& ltm);
    time_t getNow() const;
    void setNow(time_t now);
};

#endif /* TIME_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Time.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 8, 2014
 *      Author: 
 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Time.h"
#include <ctime>

Time::Time() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setNow(now);
    setLtm(ltm);
}

Time::~Time() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
void Time::tick() {
    int secund = ltm->tm_sec++;
    cout << secund << " ";

    //cout << tm;
//  time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
//  cout << t;
//      struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
//      cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-'
//           << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
//           <<  now->tm_mday << '/'
//           <<  now->tm_hour << ':'
//           << now->tm_min << ':'
//           << now->tm_sec++
//           << endl;
    //now->tm_sec++;
}

tm*& Time::getLtm() {
    return ltm;
}

void Time::setLtm(tm*& ltm) {
    this->ltm = ltm;

}

time_t Time::getNow() const {
    return now;
}

void Time::setNow(time_t now) {
    this->now = now;
}

void Time::showSec() {
    now = time(0);
    ltm = localtime(&now);
    cout << (ltm->tm_hour) << ':' << ltm->tm_min << ':' << ltm->tm_sec++;
}
```